# How to set content area div height with dynamic header div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on styling a container that has header and content area, looks like below.

```
  widget control
------------------
| header text    |  <----- header area
------------------
| item1          |
| item2          |  <---- content area
| item3          |
|                |
------------------
```

I used to use position absolute with top, bottom, left, right set to 0 to fill in the space and
displays the scrollbar in the content area if more items is added.

However the problem arise when header text is too long causing 2 or more lines:

```
 widget control

------------------
| header text    |
| long text here |  <----- header area
------------------
| item1          |
| item2          |  <---- content area
| item3          |
|                |
------------------
```

Now that header area get taller that my absolute positioning fails result in content area being overlapped by the header area.

I've setup simple example on fiddle. This example does not use position absolute approach so overlap is gone but then
since header area size cannot be predected, I'm having touch time figuring out how to set height for the content area so that scrollbar fits in to the remaining content area. (the fiddle showing that scrollbar is cut off because content area height is set to 100% which is 100% height of control itself (i.e. 100px)

http://jsfiddle.net/Lguwvwou/13/

Note that I'm looking for solution using **CSS only** and **setting static content area height (ex 50px) is not allowed**. The reason is this is widget control and user can set the control's height but they do not have control on setting height on header or content area.

So if the user set 300px height for the control, long header text could take up 100px. Then remaining height left for the content area height is 200px.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this is with flexbox:

```
.container { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.head {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.content {
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


<div class='container'>
    <div class='head'> this is head second line asdlkfj aslkf j;alksdj f;laksdjf;laksdjf;laskdf</div>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='item'>item1</div>
        <div class='item'>item2</div>
        <div class='item'>item3</div>
        <div class='item'>item4</div>
        <div class='item'>item5</div>
        <div class='item'>item6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lguwvwou/19/

Comment: Elegant Solution, is there a reason for you to sound a bit disappointed at having to use flex?

Comment: ok I understand, it breaks in some browsers including safari (may be webkit?) and of course IE (even with IE10)

Comment: Oh, I guess it came across that way... A lot of people work on sites where they can't use Flexbox because it's not supported by older browsers. I was also annoyed with myself because I couldn't find a non-CSS3 answer.

Comment: It should work in IE 10 with vendor prefixes. If you use the CSS autoprefixer plugin then it will lessen that headache for you: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core

Comment: Thanks edendramis, ultimately it would be nice to be able to support IE9 as well. I forgot to mention but +1 for working solution to modern browsers. I was looking for CSS solution because it would be cleaner than writing javascript to set the style which becomes inline style but I'm start thinking that there is no perfect solution for this with CSS only that could support IE9 as well.